# TabItems versus Parented TRectangles - Firemonkey Mobile Application

Tags: forms, mobile, embedded, tabcontrol, firemonkey

What would be more efficient in a kinda big application for a mobile application? Make a separate TabItem for each menu item or have one TabItem with an empty Rectangle that will become parent of the form of each Menu Item's Unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I assume you mean reparenting the controls on a child form to appear within a container on your main form. If so you'll need to use (e.g.) a TLayout which will handle child controls better rather than a TRectange).

It depends what you mean by 'efficient'.

One big form will take longer at start up and consume more memory.

Creating content on demand will take longer at run time as each form is created and destroyed.

Comment: Yeah but creating/destroying forms on runtime wouldn't be more efficient than loading 15-20 tabs when starting the application?

Comment: Like I said, one takes longer at start up, the other at run time. It depends where you want your inefficiencies.